# Extract link text and use as class of <a> for analytics reporting label

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to extract the link text of multiple `<a>` tags within `the_content();` of Wordpress posts, so I can use them as the class for each `<a>`. I have successfully extracted the link text and used `addClass` to classify them so we can clean up our outbound link reporting.

The problem is that it is putting each `<a>` link text as a long class for all `<a>`.

```js
var linkText = $('.entry-content a').text();
$('.entry-content a').addClass(linkText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#">sit amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <a href="#">Ut enim ad</a> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. <a href="#">Duis aute</a> irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <a href="#">Excepteur sint</a> occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
```

This code shows up in inspector shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a callback function to `.addClass()` instead like:

```js
$('.entry-content a').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#">sit amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <a href="#">Ut enim ad</a> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. <a href="#">Duis aute</a> irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <a href="#">Excepteur sint</a> occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thats it!